# Ideas for charging 12v battery

Tags: radio, speakers

I’m a 17 year old in high school, and for my class project I’m making a cooler with a car radio, and car speakers built in which is being ran off a 12 V battery. It works just fine but I have people who want to buy it and I was wondering what would be the best way for it to have a charging port of some sort or something more convenient then taking the battery out of the cooler and using a a trickle charger. I’m very new to electrical stuff, and I was wondering if anyone could shoot me some ideas, since I’m at a dead end currently.

Comment: Tweak it to use an off-the-shelf power bank, that can be charged and discharged simultaneously.

Comment: there are loads of 12v battery charger projects out there. youtube has several.

Comment: Use Subfloor adhesive to bond the power jack on the inside to the outside after drilling a hole for it.  SLA or Lithium Ion Chargers are cheap. Get connector pairs from your local shop or use Molex 4 pin connectors from your old PC HDD ports.

Comment: Just make a charging port connector for it and use it to connect the trickle charger to battery. Please note batteries are dangerous when misused, they can provide so much current that it melts wires. Always use fuses so if there ever is a mistake or accident, it's the fuse that melts, not the wires or the battery or everything that is plastic around it and start a fire.

Answer (score 0):

It is presumed that you are using a 12 V sealed lead acid gel battery.

You would need an off-the-shelf sealed lead acid gel battery charger with float-charging facility.

A barrel jack socket would have to be provided on the cooler to accommodate the barrel jack plug of the charger.

Please ensure that the charger is suitable for the Ah rating of your battery.